influx notification rule does not send the http request out
I have the following notification rule:
curl -X POST http://influx:8086/api/v2/notificationRules -H "Authorization: Token <my token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "description": "Alert on spikes detected in traffic data",
  "endpointID": "1261ec31969a7d96",                                
  "every": "15s",
  "messageTemplate": "Spike detected in {{ .Name }}: Last value: {{ index .Fields \"last\" }}, Mean: {{ index .Fields \"mean\" }}, StdDev: {{ index .Fields \"stddev\" }}",
  "name": "spike_detection_rule",
  "orgID": "a6ce0bd763dc7a0b",
  "query": {
    "text": "option task = {name: \"spike_detection_task\", every: 15s}\n\nfrom(bucket: \"one_hour\")\n  |> range(start: -15m)\n  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == \"convs_traffic_over_time_15m\")\n  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == \"all_data\")\n  |> mean()\n  |> yield(name: \"mean\")\n  |> stddev()\n  |> yield(name: \"stddev\")\n  |> last()",
    "type": "flux"
  },
  "status": "active",
  "statusRules": [
    {
      "currentLevel": "OK"
    },
    {
      "currentLevel": "CRITICAL"
    }
  ],
  "type": "http"
}

When the rule task is running it completes successfully. However, the http post request is not going out from influx. The endpoint is define in the notification endpoint for which I am specifying the endpointid in the script. The 'one_hour' bucket data looks like that:
Result: _result
Table: keys: [_start, _stop, _field, _measurement]
                   _start:time                      _stop:time           _field:string          _measurement:string                      _time:time                  _value:int
------------------------------  ------------------------------  ----------------------  ---------------------------  ------------------------------  --------------------------
2024-09-26T14:06:07.862164087Z  2024-09-26T15:06:07.862164087Z                all_data  convs_traffic_over_time_15m  2024-09-26T14:06:17.272195842Z                           0
Table: keys: [_start, _stop, _field, _measurement]
                   _start:time                      _stop:time           _field:string          _measurement:string                      _time:time                  _value:int
------------------------------  ------------------------------  ----------------------  ---------------------------  ------------------------------  --------------------------
2024-09-26T14:06:07.862164087Z  2024-09-26T15:06:07.862164087Z                   count  convs_traffic_over_time_15m  2024-09-26T14:06:17.272195842Z                           0

Is the bucket missing some information to make the rule task triggered? Is it something wrong in my rule script? influx logs do not show any details about the http post request.
Any help is appreciated.

What's the error you are getting?
